# Ruby on Rails: video object tags not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

Video objects have tags (via acts-as-taggable-on gem). The update function works for all of the video attributes except for tags. I'm not sure why. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

## views/videos/_new.html.erb

```
      <div class="">
        <%= f.label(:tag_list, "Tags (separated by commas)") %></br >
        <%= f.text_field :tag_list, multiple: true, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
```

## videos_controller.rb

```
  def edit
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
    @post = @video.post
  end

  def update
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
    @post = @video.post
    @video.update_attributes(video_params)
    if current_user == @video.user
      if @video.save
        flash[:notice] = "Video successfully updated!"
        redirect_to video_path(@video)
      else
        flash[:notice] = "Video was not updated."
        @errors = @video.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
        flash[:alert] = @errors
        render action: "edit"
      end
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Only OP can edit video"
      refresh :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def video_params
    params.require(:video).permit(
      :title,
      :url,
      :tag_list,
    )
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your video_params is filtering it.

Try

```
 params.require(:video).permit(
      :title,
      :url,
      tag_list: []
    )
```

Comment: That was a partial solution (thank you!). If I edit a video with 4 tags ["mustache", "ubernostrum", "more words"], it will fill the text_field with all three tags without the commas and thus save it as though it were one single tag item.

Comment: no problem. I would like an upvote and correct answer though please :) trying to get to 500 points.

Comment: Still trying to figure out why it is stripping out all the commas in update in the edit form text_field and thus concatenating all the tags.

Comment: What does your object do with the data? What does your schema look like? Maybe you want to create an model for the tags, then use a nested attribute set up?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html . I can't tell from your question but its very possible this would be a better route.